# How should I find inner classes using jquery. I am new to this, so I know how to select a single class but not the inner classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to access buttons_1?

```
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 left">

    <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" id="buttons_1" >Yo Money</button>
```

Comment: `buttons_1` is an id and while id should be unique (used for just one element) you can directly use `$('#buttons_1')`

Comment: Thanks, that worked now how should I access inner classes?

Comment: it will be easier to say what're you trying to do .. and what do you mean with **access**?? .. Also do you've multiple `row`s and each row has a button in it??

Answer (score 1):

You can refer with `id` or use use the `tag`

```
$('#buttons_1'); // ID
$('.row button'); // Tag
```

```js
console.log($('#buttons_1'));
console.log($('.row button'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 left">
    <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" id="buttons_1">Yo Money</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `id` selector can do the job like `$("#buttons_1")`

```js
$("#buttons_1").click(function(e){

  alert(1)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 left">
    <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg" type="button" id="buttons_1" >Yo Money</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: that worked, now how should I access inner classes?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can access elements by Id with #id. It doesn't matter on which hierarchy they are. You should learn about selectors.

```
$("#buttons_1"). // do whatever you want
```